# Downloading html inputs to text file to C drive local folder

Tags: html

I have just started out and we student’s and I have created an online work book but can’t get the answers to download to text file, it downloads but when we open file it comes up with undefined here is my code.

This works with outlook but students don’t have outlook they have office 365 web based email and I am not allowed to use our smtp server
Email appears like this

Name=Student’s name shown here
1.1= answers are shown here 
1.2=
1.3=
1.4=
1.5=
1.6=
And so on

Here is an example of my code

```
<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, ['text'].value, ['id'].value)">


<h4>Students Name<input type="text" name="Name" value="" size="50"><br></h4>
 <br>
<h4>1. Why is it important to think about safety?</h4>

<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value=" A" id="q1a" />it identifies where the risks are.</label></p>
<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value=" B" id="q1b" />because I may get hurt.</label></p>
<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value=" C" id="q1c" />because it may prevent accidents and keep everyone safe.</label></p>
<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value=" D" id="q1d"/>because it will keep others safe.</label></p>
<br>


<h4>11. Respirators should be used to prevent?</h4>
<input type="text" name="1.11" id="1.11" size= "120"></p>
<br>
<h4>12. Disposable gloves are optional but do provide a convenient way to avoid?</h4>

<input type="text" name="1.12" id="1.12" size= "120"></p>
<br>
<h4>13. Why should you prevent liquid oil and grease from entering the pores of your skin?</h4>

<input type="text" name="1.13" id="1.13" size= "120"></p>
<br>

<h4>14. Why shouldn't we use hot water to wash off grease and oil off our hands?</h4>


<input type="text" name="1.14" id="1.14" size= "120"></p>
<br>

<h4>15. List 3 things that may cause a fire or act as a fuel?</h4>
<p>a.   <input type="text" name="1.15a" id="1.15a" size= "117"></p>
<p>b.   <input type="text" name="1.15b" id="1.15b" size= "117"></p>
<p>c.   <input type="text" name="1.15c" id="1.15c" size= "117"></p>

  <input type="submit" value="Download">
  </style>
<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);

 pom.click();

  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I am really new to coding as you can see from my question. My students and have come up with and safety web page to use in house at school and want to save input data to text file.  The outlook bit is that I can get it to email on outlook with the form method=post action=mailto  but my students don't have outlook access so we want to save as a downloadable text file on their computers.

Comment: Here are a couple of questions <h4>1. Respirators should be used to prevent?</h4>
<input type="text" name="1.1" id="1.1" size= "120"></p>
<br>
<h4>2. Disposable gloves are optional but do provide a convenient way to avoid?</h4>
<input type="text" name="1.2" id="1.2" size= "120"></p>
<br>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, the problem is, that you call the download function with undefined arguments. 
To get the data from your form, you can loop through

```
document.getElementById('yourFrom').elements
```

and safe the name-value pairs in an object. And then you can pass that object to your download function.

My example code collects the form data in the function

```
getFormData()
```

that is called by clicking the button instead of submitting the form.

Since you have radio buttons in your questions form, the loop should check for 
it and safe only the selected value. I put comments in my example code to 
explain how this is done.

I commented out the function

```
download()
```

because I think it wouldn't be a good idea to make people here download the file. 
But you can see, what is safed in the file, when you open the dev-tools of your 
browser. Therefor I put the line

```
console.log(...);
```

I also put some example values in the form here in the code snippet for convenience.

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  /*var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
  pom.setAttribute('target', new Date());
  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);
  pom.click();
  document.body.removeChild(pom);*/
  console.log('filename: ' + filename);
  console.log('text: ' + text);
}

/* get the Data from questions form */
function getFormData() {
  var form = document.getElementById("questionsForm");
  var questions = form.elements;
  var ret_obj ={};
  var radios = [];
  for(var i = 0 ; i < questions.length ; i += 1){
    var item = questions.item(i);
    if (item.type == 'radio') {
      /* if question input type is radio */
      if (radios.indexOf(item.name) == -1) {
         /* safe radio group name in array radios
         to prevent check on other radios of the same group */
        radios.push(item.name);
        /* safe radio group name and checked value in ret_obj */
        ret_obj[item.name] = document.querySelector('input[name="' + item.name + '"]:checked').value;
      }
    } else {
      /* if question input is different from radio
         safe the name-value pair in ret_obj */
      ret_obj[item.name] = item.value;        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ret_obj));
    download('yourFilename', JSON.stringify(ret_obj));
  }
```

```html
<div>
<form id="questionsForm">

<h4>Students Name<input type="text" name="Name" value="TheStudentsName" size="50"></h4>

<h4>1. Why is it important to think about safety?</h4>
<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value="A" id="q1a" />it identifies where the risks are.</label></p>
<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value="B" id="q1b" checked/>because I may get hurt.</label></p>
<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value="C" id="q1c" />because it may prevent accidents and keep everyone safe.</label></p>
<p><label for="q1"><input type="radio" name="1.1" value="D" id="q1d"/>because it will keep others safe.</label></p>


<h4>11. Respirators should be used to prevent?</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="1.11" id="1.11" size= "120" value="answer11"></p>

<h4>12. Disposable gloves are optional but do provide a convenient way to avoid?</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="1.12" id="1.12" size= "120" value="answer12"></p>

<h4>13. Why should you prevent liquid oil and grease from entering the pores of your skin?</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="1.13" id="1.13" size= "120" value="answer13"></p>

<h4>14. Why shouldn't we use hot water to wash off grease and oil off our hands?</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="1.14" id="1.14" size= "120" value="answer14"></p>

<h4>15. List 3 things that may cause a fire or act as a fuel?</h4>
<p>a.   <input type="text" name="1.15a" id="1.15a" size= "117" value="answer15a"></p>
<p>b.   <input type="text" name="1.15b" id="1.15b" size= "117" value="answer15b"></p>
<p>c.   <input type="text" name="1.15c" id="1.15c" size= "117" value="answer15c"></p>

</form>
<button onclick="getFormData()">getFormData</button>
</div>
```

*Btw: Instead of the outdated*

```
<script language="Javascript"></script>
```

*you should use*

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To make the text in the file better readable, you can use the third parameter of [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
JSON.stringify(ret_obj, null, '\t')
```

---

**Update**

In the above example **unanswered question from input fields** are simply not 
safed. To require an answer you can use the <input> attribute *required*.

```
<!-- example for required attribute of input element -->
<h4>11. Respirators should be used to prevent?</h4>
<p><input type="text" name="1.11" id="1.11" size= "120" required></p>
```

However **questions from radio buttons** are required, otherwise the script will throw an error because in the line

```
ret_obj[item.name] = document.querySelector('input[name="' + item.name + '"]:checked').value;
```

`document.querySelector('input[name="' + item.name + '"]:checked')` is *null* if no radio button of the group is checked and *null* has no property *value*.

As w3.org [states](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute):

> To avoid confusion as to whether a radio button group is required or not, authors are encouraged to specify the attribute on all the radio buttons in a group. Indeed, in general, authors are encouraged to avoid having radio button groups that do not have any initially checked controls in the first place, as this is a state that the user cannot return to, and is therefore generally considered a poor user interface.

In fact only one of the radio buttons of a group needs the attribute *required* to make the group required. Or there should be a preselected radio button like in the following example.

```
<h4>1. Who is the owner of my socks?</h4>
<p><label for="q1a">
  <input type="radio" name="socksOwner" value="me" id="q1a">me
</label></p>
<p><label for="q1b">
  <input type="radio" name="socksOwner" value="JohnDoe" id="q1b" />John Doe
</label></p>
<p><label for="q1c">
  <input type="radio" name="socksOwner" value="NA" id="q1c" checked/>I don't know
</label></p>
```

However, **if you don't want an answer to a question with radio buttons to be required or preselected**, we need to handle that in the script. Therefor we check if there is one item of a group selected and only if that's the case safe the value. To achieve that, change this line

```
ret_obj[item.name] = document.querySelector('input[name="' + item.name + '"]:checked').value;
```

to this:

```
/* checked item in radio group*/
var selRadio = document.querySelector('input[name="' + item.name + '"]:checked');
/* if one of the radio buttons in the group is checked, safe value */
if (selRadio !== null) {
  ret_obj[item.name] = selRadio.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I need it! I was going to get students to download them so they could email them to me through their office 365 accounts as an attachment.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please consider upvoting/accepting it.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer I copied it to notepad++ but cannot get it to work but I can get it work on run code snippet, i'll keep working on it, thanks again

Comment: Don't forget to comment the part in the download function in again that I commented out.

Comment: Thanks I got it! thank you so much greatly appreciated, I've two other questions if you don't mind, 1st Can I get it to save answers for those students that don't finish it in one lesson and I can i get the downloaded answers as a list, thanks again

Comment: If the studends can save their files without answering all questions. The not answered questions are not in the file then. To make the output better readable, you can use the third parameter of [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Olafant that looks great. Sorry to annoy you is there a maximum number of characters that students can type in their answers. When I add code to full questionnaire it will not download but when I change < questions.length ; i += 1)  the 1 I can get the name only to download. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you have additional questions, please ask a new question. You can put a link here to the new question if you like.

Comment: Sorry additional questions in my form.

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind, that comments are not meant to be permanent. It's better for you and me (reputation) and better for SO to keep different questions separated. So other people with the same question can search and find a solution for their problem.

Comment: Thanks heaps got that to work, but all radio button questions have to be answered for it to getformData is there a way that we get it to getformdata with some or none of radio button questions answered as students may not get to them in that lesson

Comment: Permanent as in contrary of temporary. Please check my update to find out, how to handle not required radio answers.